# Go to top frame in pdb (python debugger)

Tags: python, debugging

When pdb / ipdb is used in post-mortem mode, it drops you into an interactive shell where you can explore the environment at the stack frame of the most deeply nested code. I'm usually not interested in the the situation several levels down into some library -- I'm interested in my function because that's what really caused the problem. So, most of the time I have to press "u" several times to get back up to the level of the code I wrote.

Is there a way I can jump to the "top" to speed this up? Or even better, a shortcut to go straight to a particular stack frame?

(By the way, the stack feels a little "upside down" to me here. A function that calls another function puts the new call on the top of the stack, right? So I feel like the pdb u(p) command is actually moving you down into the stack...)

Comment: It's a stacktrace, not a stack. It's how it went through the stack. That's why it ends at the deep end.

Comment: Ah, good point. That addresses my sneaky add-on question.

Comment: Not really an answer, but the "hack" I used it to copy and paste `u;; u;; u;;` a bunch of times.  It's faster than typing `u<RET>` over and over.

Comment: u 99 will move you to the top, unless your program has more than 99 frames. overshooting does not cause problems when i tested it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a PdbExtension for this.

See https://github.com/fschulze/pytest-pdb/pull/5 where this is about to be added to pytest-pdb.

Comment: Ooh, that's cool. I would quite like to be able to jump into my code by default.

Answer (score 8):

You could do "up n" with an arbitrarily high value for n, like 99:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-up

PS. It was mentioned by Chris in a comment on the OP.
I do re-post it as an answer to make it more visible, and with a link to the documentation.